# TypeError: nft.createToken(...) is not a function error

Tags: solidity, hardhat, test

I created an ERC721 token using openzeppelin like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Item is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    address contractAddress;

    constructor(address marketAddress) ERC721("Item", "ITM") {
        contractAddress = marketAddress;
    }

    function createToken(string memory _URI)
        public
        returns(uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 itemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, itemId);
        _setTokenURI(itemId, _URI);
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return itemId;
    }
}
```

In this contract, I have a function `createToken` for minting tokens. I use hardhat for tests and I got this error: `TypeError: nft.createToken(...) is not a function`

```
/* deploy the NFT contract */
    const Item = await ethers.getContractFactory("Item")
    const nft = await Item.deploy(marketAddress)
    await nft.deployed()
    /* create two tokens */
    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation.com")
    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation2.com")
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you aren't getting the right javascript object. Try:

```
    const Item = await ethers.getContractFactory("Item")
    await Item.deploy(marketAddress)
    const nft = await nft.deployed()
    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation.com")
```